# Kendo grid - Grouping is not working with custom editor drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using a kendo grid with grouping enabled with inline edit options. one column is using custom editor drop down list. when I am trying to group with that specific column I am getting error like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` I created a similar situation in following sample http://dojo.telerik.com/@jomet/EXeqE  --try to group with category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reference the field within Category that you want to group by when defining your columns in the widget initialization.  You're referencing 'Category', but you need to reference 'Category.CategoryName'.
So in your Dojo example, change this:

```
{ field: "Category", title: "Category", width: "180px", editor: categoryDropDownEditor, template: "#=Category.CategoryName#" },
```

to this:

```
{ field: "Category.CategoryName", title: "Category", width: "180px", editor: categoryDropDownEditor, template: "#=Category.CategoryName#" },
```

and you should be good to go!